# how to remove hierarchical column names

Tags: python, pandas

The following line of code does what I need:

```py
df=df.groupby('Continent').agg({'PopEst': ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']})
```

However the result is:

```
PopEst                                          
                size           sum          mean           std
Continent                                                     
Asia               5  2.898666e+09  5.797333e+08  6.790979e+08
Australia          1  2.331602e+07  2.331602e+07           NaN
Europe             6  4.579297e+08  7.632161e+07  3.464767e+07
North America      2  3.528552e+08  1.764276e+08  1.996696e+08
South America      1  2.059153e+08  2.059153e+08           NaN
```

If I print(list(df.columns)) I get this:

```
[('PopEst', 'size'), ('PopEst', 'sum'), ('PopEst', 'mean'), ('PopEst', 'std')]
```

I need the above line to print (size, sum, mean and std)

how can I remove the PopEst father column without deleting the sub columns

Comment: I have fear close this, because then it seems I have something wrong with you :(

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent it by pass aggregate functions in list and specify column after `groupby`:

```
df=df.groupby('Continent')['PopEst'].agg(['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std'])
```

In your solution remove first level in `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
df=df.groupby('Continent').agg({'PopEst': ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']})
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
```